# Definite article or zero article?

Tags: articles, definite-articles, zero-article

I am writing a mathematical paper. There is a certain sequence (3) in the paper. I write:

> **Lemma 4.5.**  *The sequence (3) is exact.*

Is that correct, or should I better write with the zero article, like this?

> **Lemma 4.5.**  *Sequence (3) is exact.*

EDIT: I write a formula of a special kind, that we call "a sequence of groups and homomorphisms". This formula has a number, in my case it has number 3. After I write this formula, I claim that it has a certain property: it is "exact". The question is: should write with the *definite* article "The sequence (3)" or with the *zero* article "Sequence (3)"?

Comment: What is the phrase trying to convey?

Comment: I write a formula of a special kind, that we call "a sequence of groups and homomorphisms".  This formula has a number, in my case it has number 3. I claim that this formula has a certain property: it is "exact". The question is: should write with the *definite* article "The sequence (3)" or with the  *zero* article "Sequence (3)"?

Comment: Please add that comment to the OP. That said, if "Sequence (3)" is the name of the sequence, in a proper sense, I would recommend using the zero article. If you just want to say "the third sequence is exact", then go with "the".

Comment: @Hank: Thank you! Yes, "Sequence (3)" is like a name. I will use the zero article.

Comment: Related: [Why do we not use the definite article in “Where can I find the room 401?”](//ell.stackexchange.com/q/73709/357)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also write, "the sequence in (3) is exact." If it's an equation, I'll usually write "Equation (3) is...," but I'll also write "the expression in (3) is..." I don't think it really matters, as this is an exotic use of English.

Comment: What's "exotic" about this? *Sequence (3)* is the name of formula and *the sequence (3)* consists of a noun and a restrictive appositive.